# Using card layout.

Tags: cardlayout

I made this simple program of a library that offers a user to do different functions like issuing books and adding members etc. I want to make the output in form of graphics.

Now the problem is that I want to use CardLayout and it's a bit difficult for me to understand.

I tried searching online and read articles and other answers but they all are a bit complicated.

If anyone could give me a basic and simple explanation or code to make it easy for me to understand.

I know using panels and buttons and text fields etc. Only problem is how should I write the code to let user change the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?
First create panels:

```
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
```

and now you can create CardLayout:

```
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, "Text");
cards.add(card2, "Text");
```